# How to configure the default ActiveMQ in tomEE

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I'm very new to ActiveMQ, and would like to have some help in setting up the default internal ActiveMQ broker of tomEE. To be specific, any sample of TOMEE.xml would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a look to http://tomee.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html ?

Comment: Yes, I did try the configuration for Internal ActiveMQ Broker. However, I'm not getting the following line:
<Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
- is this resource need to be written by me, or it refers to the default one?
- Also, do I need to keep activemq.xml in the conf folder?

Comment: the resource adapter has a default, up to you to use it or not (it uses an embedded broker: https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/container/openejb-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/org.apache.openejb/service-jar.xml#L668)

activemq.xml is not used by default so you can specify the location you want.